# If Internet Explorer - Add Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

I'm trying to dynamically add a script if a user is using Internet explorer. I tried IE Conditionals but chrome didn't like the `!IE` tag so I'm trying it the jquery way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($.browser.msie){
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="ie/ieFix.js" ></script>');
    }
    else{
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="dynamic.js" ></script>');
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure why its not letting me just add this, instead it returns `'); } else{ document.write(''); }`

Throwing them in variables has the same effect :/

**IE Conditionals**

```
<!--[if !ie]>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dynamic.js" ></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if ie]>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ie/ieFix.js" ></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `</script>` in the line

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="ie/ieFix.js" ></script>');
```

actually matches as the end tag of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

on the line above it. You should rewrite it to something like

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="ie/ieFix.js" ></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

so you don't confuse the browser with the closing `</script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Any IE check

```
function detectIEEdge() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
       // Edge => return version number
       return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
}
```

Comment: tested in IE11. It's returning false 

Comment: Updated just now.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome works fine with `!IE` if you do it right:

```
<!--[if !ie]>-->
    Put stuff for non-IE browsers here
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The reason you are having problems in your code above is because the HTML parser sees the `</script>` as the end of the script rather than a part of the string. People usually fix this by using `<\/script>`.

---

Update: You're doing your "if IE" wrong now.

```
<!--[if ie]>
    IE stuff - this is a "conditional reveal"
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !ie]>-->
    Non-IE stuff - this is a "conditional hide"
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Also even if I add a `if ie` conditional, it default to the ie version in chrome. I edited my answer with my ie conditionals.